# True or false set question

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The smallest positive integer in the set $\{6u + 9v : u,v=\text{integers}\}$ is $1$.

My thoughts: false. there is no value of $u$ and $v$ (positive or negative) that could result in a remainder of $1$.  Smallest positive I get is $3$.  Solid foundation to prove it?

Answer (score 2):

The key phrase here in the more general case is [Bezout's lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity).

---

But in this case, just note that every number of the form $6u + 9v$ is divisible by $3$, since

$$6u + 9v = 3(2u + 3v)$$

But $1$ isn't.